Upper bound on Kolmogorov Complexity using compression algorithms
I have seen several posts that derive a good upper bound to KC of an arbitrary string using a compression algorithm like GZIP. However, these posts often seem to indicate the KC upper bound is simply the length of the compressed string, while ignoring the decompression process. As I understand it, for an arbitrary string S and a compression program C:
$$ KC(s) \leq |C(s)| + |C| $$
So I'd have to add the size of the decompression algorithm to the compressed data to get the actual bound. What I don't understand is that given how large the source code of modern compression algorithms might be, this doesn't actually seem to be a very good upper bound at all. Am I missing something?

The short answer is you can't decompress a file without the information of the decompresser.
Upper Bound Using Compression
To estimate an upper bound on Kolmogorov Complexity using compression, you consider the size of the compressed data plus the size of the decompression algorithm. The idea is that the combination of these two constitutes an alternative, concise description of the original data.
Size of Decompression Algorithm: You rightly noted that the size of a general compression library could be quite large. However, when discussing Kolmogorov Complexity, it's important to note that the decompression program accounted for should ideally be the minimal one that can successfully decompress the string, potentially stripping away unnecessary parts of the library. In theoretical contexts or competitions, there's an emphasis on optimizing the decompressor to be as small as possible, sometimes writing specialized code rather than using full libraries.

Kolmogorov complexity is only defined up to some additive constant (because there is no canonical choice of program interpreter), so talking about the Kolmogorov complexity of a single string in isolation is meaningless anyway.

True, but with a fixed interpreter it's meaningful to compare several generating programs for a string... accounting for the decompression algorithm makes this comparison meaningful when including arbitrary programs
